# DOM Manipulation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This should be fairly simple, but I seem to be missing something. I'm working on a little project in which the code that I'm writing aims to do a few things across the document. Here's the HTML code that I want to apply my script's actions to:

```
<div class="entry">
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
    <p>One more...</p>

    <div class="bttn"><a href="#">Click for More</a></div>
</div>
```

This template (that is, several **p** elements and one **div** with the class "bttn" inside a wrapper **div** with the class "entry") is repeated multiple times across the document. Users add content to the paragraphs and eventually publish it to the site. And here's what I wish to do in my .js file:

1. Count all **p** elements inside the **div** elements with the class
   "entry".
2. Throughout the entire document, if there are more than two **p** elements inside each **div** classed "entry", I want to leave the *first two* untouched and move the rest to a new **div** element with the class "slider". This new element would be placed after the "Click for More" button.
3. Add the class "show" to the already existent **div** element classed "bttn", but *only* to those that belong to the classes "entry" that contained more than two paragraphs and were moved to the new **div** with the class "slider". The new button would look like this: div class="bttn slider" (plus the anchor tag and everything else as shown in the template).

So basically, if the user who published the content added more than two paragraphs to the HTML template, when the doc is ready I want the script to take the other paragraphs, move them to a new **div** element, and add a new class to the button. In the end when the "Click for More" button is clicked, the extra paragraphs that were removed and inserted afterwards will fade in nicely (since I'll keep them hidden under the button once I've re-inserted them). Here's what I've done so far:

```
$('.entry').each(function () {
    $counter = $('.entry p').length;

    if ($counter > 2) {
        $removeExtra = $(this).find('p').not(':eq(1)').not(':eq(0)').detach();

        $(this).find('.bttn').after(function () {
            return '<div class="slider">' + $removeExtra.html() + '</div>';
        }).addClass('show');
    }
});
```

**Issues:**

- We all know that the **html()** method will only return the first set
  of matched elements, so on button click I only get the first
  paragraph that was removed from each class "entry", and I need to get
  back *all* detached paragraphs that I stored in the variable
  $removeExtra.
- Every **div** element with the class "bttn" is getting the new class "show", and I *only* want this to happen to those that belong to the classes "entry" that saw some extra paragraphs removed. The div class="entry" elements that had two paragraphs from the beginning should see no modification in the button's class.

Would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$counter = $('.entry p').length;
```

Is finding all paragraphs within *any* ".entry" div, when you want paragraphs just within the *current* ".entry" div. Also you don't need to use the callback-function syntax with [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) since you're using it to add after only one element at a time.

Try this instead:

```
$('.entry').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $p = $this.find('p');

    if ($p.length > 2) {
        $('<div class="slider"/>').appendTo(this).append($p.slice(2));
        $this.find('.bttn').addClass('show');
    }
});
```

I've used [the `.append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) rather than `.after()` since `.append()` will automatically add them after the last child of the element you're appending to. You don't need to detach the paragraphs before appending them to the new div because `.append()` will *move* them (at least, it will move them when there is only one target element - as is the case here).

I've used [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) rather than your `.not(':eq(1)').not(':eq(0)')`.

Note that you should declare variables with `var` or they become globals.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make your response so detailed — I've learned more than what I was asking for. Thumbs up! I've got a quick question, though — would it make any difference whatsoever to do .addClass('slider') instead of inserting the div element along with the class itself too? Cheers.

Comment: `$("<div/>").addClass("slider")` (as shown in Jonathan's answer) would work fine, in fact I think that's a better way to do it. You can still chain `.appendTo()` or whatever other methods you need.

Answer (score 3):

My initial suggestion would be to use `:gt`:

```
$(".entry").each(function(){
    var ps = $("p:gt(1)", this);
    if ( ps.length ) {
        $(".bttn", this).addClass("show").after(function(){
            return $("<div>").addClass("slider").append(ps);    
        });
    }        
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I apologize if I got the details mixed up in any degree - the question is a bit verbose.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FfmaB/1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up implementing a mixture of nnnnnn's approach and yours. It works great. Thanks one more time.

Comment: @Jonathan - I think you need `if (ps.length)` rather than `if (ps)` (because `ps` will always be truthy).

Comment: @nnnnnn Good eye. Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

review the documentation for `$.html()` function:
http://api.jquery.com/html/

> If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

I believe this is what you wanted:

```
$(document).ready(Process);

function Process() {
    $('.entry').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $counter = $this.find('p').length;

        if ($counter > 2) {
            var $Extras = $this.find('p').not(':eq(1)').not(':eq(0)');

            $($Extras.get().reverse()).each(function() {
                var extra = $(this).html();
                $this.find('.bttn').after('<div class="slider">' + extra + '</div>');
                $this.find('p').not(':eq(1)').not(':eq(0)').detach();
            })
            $this.find(".bttn").addClass('show');
        }
    });
}​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xcuh9/2/

regards,
Nitin J.

Comment: Thank you. I went with nnnnnn's approach mostly and it works great. However, your post was helpful too. Thanks again.